# Swift custom flatMap implementation causes error Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to implement a custom `flatMap` on a struct that has some generic items. The `flatMap` would just `Swift.flatMap` over the items using the provided transform function. The code here is a bit contrived, but it boggles my mind why the standard library version does not cause an error, but mine does.

Is there something I'm missing in my implementation of `flatMap`?

```
struct Wrapper<T:NSObject> {

    let items:[T]

    func flatMap<U>(_ transform:(T) -> U?) -> Wrapper<U> {
        let newItems = items.flatMap { transform($0) }
        return Wrapper<U>(items: newItems)
    }
}

protocol Something {}

let wrapper = Wrapper<UIView>(items: [UIView()])

// Using standard library flatMap
wrapper
    .items
    .flatMap { $0 as? Something } // ✅ No error
    // ..

// Using custom flatMap
wrapper
    .flatMap { $0 as? Something } //  ERROR: Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
    // ..
```

Comment: Why the `NSObject` constraint on `T`? `Something` is a protocol, so doesn't inherit from `NSObject`, so you cannot have `Wrapper<Something>`.

Comment: There may be a conformance somewhere else in the code like `extension UIView : Something {}`, in which case it makes sense to attempt the cast.

Comment: But what if you had `struct Foo : Something`? That can be cast to `Something`, but doesn't inherit from `NSObject`. If you really need the `NSObject` constraint, you could say `wrapper.flatMap { $0 as? NSObject & Something }` (in Swift 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Something` does not conform to `NSObject`.

Swift 4 automatically infers constraints for the generic parameter `U` used in your `flatMap` function by looking at all parameters which include `U`. `U` is used as a generic parameter to `Wrapper` which requires `U: NSObject`. `Something` is not a subclass of `NSObject`.

The error message is just misleading.

Comment: I removed "Wrappable" from the example code (fairly quickly after I posted).

Comment: `Something` is still just a Swift Protocol and not a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: So, how does that explain why the stdlib version works on `items` which the compiler can also infer is an `NSObject`? and I agree the error message is probably misleading.

Comment: @DavidJames, stdlib version doesn't declare that type is restricted to `NSObject` at all. Your problem is here: `<T:NSObject>`.

Comment: @user28434 This makes all the sense. (and makes more sense of the other posters comments) Thanks!